# Even If I wrote all the code, After checking the checkboxes nothing is being added to the listbbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

## SERVER SIDE SCRIPT

I wrote this code to make a web form that ADDS or REMOVES items in the Listbox when the checkbox is checked or unchecked but even after checking and unchecking the checkboxes nothing is happening.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style = "background-color:darksalmon; font-style:oblique; font-family:'Gill Sans MT'">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <center>
                <table border="3" border-color="black">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" border="2" align="center">
                            <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="414px" Width="316px"></asp:ListBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style1">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="PHP" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged" Text="JAVA" />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" Text="C" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
  protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox1.Text);
        }

    }

    protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox2.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox2.Text);
        }
    }

    protected void CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox3.Checked == true)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(CheckBox3.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(CheckBox3.Text);
        }
    }
```

---

I tried to change the coding at "`protected-void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`"
but nothing is being added to the list even after checking the checkbox.!!

Comment: have you tried putting breakpoint and see whether the checkedchange events are getting called?

Comment: AutoPostBack="true" was not checked done by me